# HVAC condenser fan overheating/shutting down turns out a bad control board

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, central-air

[image][image][image][image][image][image]Two weeks ago my condenser fan started overheating after 15 to 30 minutes of runtime. Seeing as capacitors are cheap I replace the capacitor first. The problem persisted so I ordered a new fan motor. Same specs 1/4hp 825rpm 2amp from Novac. The problem still persists. Thinking voltage through the contactor may be the issue I replaced the contactor as well. Problem still persists. Cleaned coils cleaned all electrical connections. I'm at a loss could a low charge cause overheating of the coils and in turn cause the motor to overheat. Photos A/C unit https://imgur.com/a/ZcImE4C

Comment: What is the voltage to the motor?  Over or under volt can make it overworked and overheat.  How did you determine it is overheating?

Comment: Are these motors 120 V or 240 V/

Comment: 241V reading at the black and white wires going to the fan. Figured out it's overheating because when it shuts of the fan motor is to hot to touch.

Comment: 208-230V is what the tag reads

Comment: Also just remembered when if cuts out the contactor will not disengage until I flip the breaker even if it's off at the thermostat the contactor attempts to stay engaged until power is cut completely.  This only happens when the fan shuts down though. Don't know if it's important but it seems odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be the defrost control board. I was able to retrofit a White Rodgers Universal defrost control board and everything seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Good job, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

Too hot to touch may be perfectly normal. Quoting from drivesandautomation.co.uk:

> Heat kills, and the old standard of using your hand to judge the
> temperature of a motor and if it was over heating no longer applies.
> NEMA Insulation Classes do away with guessing, and give the motor
> manufacturer a defined framework to operate in. The Surface
> temperature of the motor is typically 30°C lower than it is at the
> windings. So if we look at a Class F insulated motor which will be
> happy running at 155°C and then subtract 30°C, we get a surface
> temperature of 125°C. This doesn't necessarily mean it is running too
> hot or operating improperly (by the way, we strongly advise against
> touching anything that is 125°C).  To put it simply, today's motors
> can simply be too hot to handle, even when all is working as it should
> be.
>
> Motor winding insulation max temperature ratings carry NEMA
> designations.   These ratings are defined as:
>
> Class: A  105 Degrees C
>
> Class: B  130 Degrees C
>
> Class: F  155 Degrees C
>
> Class: H  180 Degrees C

[Continue reading the article](http://www.drivesandautomation.co.uk/useful-information/nema-insulation-classes/).

So if your motor has Class F insulation, which is commonplace for A/C condenser fan motors, the outer case could actually sizzle when you touch it with a wet finger, and it would still be within the normal working temperature range.

You can measure the temperature of the case with a non-contact IR thermometer. You generally have to point one of those at a painted surface because a bare metal surface gives a false reading.

Comment: OK good info, so if not heat then what is shutting the motor down. I don't have any kind of thermometer to measure the temp but it will turn back on after it cools down.

Comment: @Richard Neither your original post nor your comments to answer the queries before I provided this answer mentioned that something is shutting down the fan motor *while the compressor is still running* and with the thermostat not calling for cooling. That's what you're saying now, right? All you said before is that the motor feels hot after it turns off. Provide a schematic for your A/C to further the diagnosis.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying sorry for the misunderstanding. It's hard to provide a schematic due to all the labels being to faded to read a model name or number to find a schematic. The only thing I know for sure is that it's a Ruud split heat pump unit. If there's a way to add photos on here I could take some photos but that's the best I can do. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: @Richard To add photos, click EDIT on your question, then use the icon that looks like mountains to add photos. You can also search online for a schematic. You'll need the make and model number of your A/C. Look for a metal name plate on the unit, which should have model and serial numbers.

Comment: Added a link to photos the site wouldn't let me upload due to being to large

Comment: @Richard Either resize them in an image editor or change your camera settings to take smaller photos.

Comment: Resized and added

Comment: @Richard Referencing the last photo only, which capacitor did you change? Upper left, center right or lower right? Which contactor? Center only? I'm hoping this dialog generates a chat invitation; I have a lot of comments.

Comment: All 3 capacitors were replaced and the center contactor was replaced.

Comment: @Richard The center contactor appears to be for the compressor and not related to the fan. The aftermarket upper left capacitor is a hard-start kit that helps the compressor start under conditions of low voltage. It is not essential to the operation of the A/C. The relay or contactor in the lower left is probably for the fan motor. The one in the upper right that is no longer in use may have been for the reversing valve, and may have been replaced by the relay in the upper left. Hard to be sure without a schematic and/or tracing the wires.

Comment: @Richard The gray plastic box with electronics on the outside of the unit is a radio receiver that the electric company can use to turn off your A/C for a time during high demand. If this was set up during a previous ownership and you do not have a load shedding agreement with the company, you can disconnect it by killing the power, finding, disconnecting and re- insulating where the unseen other ends of the red, black and white wires from the transformer are connected to a power source. Then disconnect the two yellow wires and jumper the thermostat wires that they are connected to.

Comment: @Richard The tray metal box with electronics at the top of the first photo is the antiquated "brain" of the unit that contains timing and logic controls. I fear that there may be a defect in that box due to age, and probably not repairable due to unavailability of parts. You can try placing a table fan right up against the open box (temporarily) to blow on the electronics to try to keep them cool while you run the A/C, and see if that allows the fan to run continuously.

Comment: 10-4 I'll remove the radio box and try cooling the brain after work tomorrow. I appreciate the suggestions and will post results. The chat option has came up but I guess I'm to new to use it. It gives me an error when I click on it.

Comment: @Richard The only other diagnostic that I can recommend at this point is to trace wiring from the fan motor to the relay/contactor that serves it and take voltage readings at the relay both when the fan runs and when it quits to determine if the fan is still getting power when it quits (meaning there's an internal motor thermal cutout) or if the relay is energized but not conducting power (replace it), or if the relay is de-energized by the control logic (bad electronics in the gray metal box).

Comment: @Richard Rats, I think you need a minimum 20 reputation to chat.

Comment: looks like it's something going bad in the defrost control circuitry. The brown relay, the clear relay and the circuit board are all part of this system. None of these parts are available. I am going to attempt a retrofit with a White Rodgers universal control board. I'll update with results to finalize this question.

Comment: @Richard Fingers crossed.

Comment: BTW @MTA thought you would find it interesting. I found a date on the unit. It's from 1985 and now back up and running.